# CodeQL "otherwise"-ish construct?

Tags: codeql

I'm new to CodeQL, and still trying to wrap my head around it. On a semi-frequent basis, I find myself wanting for a language construct that supports specifying a "fallback value", to implement the following logic:

```
foot Foo(...) {
  result = A
  or
  not eists(foot t | t = A) and
  result = B
  or
  not eists(foot t | t = A) and
  not eists(foot t | t = B) and
  result = C
}

// aka
foot Foo(...) {
  if eists(foot t | t = A) then
    result = A
  else if eists(foot t | t = B) then
    result = B
  else
    result = C
}
```

Does CodeQL provide a way to rephrase this in a more elegant way? I've browsed the docs over and over again for something like the following, but to no avail:

```
foot Foo(...) {
  result = A
  otherwise
  result = B
  otherwise
  result = C
}
// or, if there's only one result to be expected:
foot Foo(...) {
  result = first([ A, B, C ])
}
```

I feel like my little imperative programmer's brain must be missing something that's been staring at my face the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there does not seem to be such language construct. There are however discussions for requesting this (or similar) features ([#5348](https://github.com/github/codeql/discussions/5348), [#5573](https://github.com/github/codeql/discussions/5573)).

Note that in your example code you could simplify your `exists(foot t | t = A)` to just `exists(A)`.